# Getting "Value Cannot be Null" when selecting elements from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So i have an MVC program that sends information from View form to an XML file. Now this information writes correctly but a break is caused each time due to the following error and i cant understand why!

[image]

above is my constructor within ScorecardRepository.cs and the following is my code for my model, namely Scorecard.cs

```
public partial class Scorecard
{
    public int ScorecardID { get; set; }
    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public Scorecard()
    {
        this.ScorecardID = 0;
        this.VendorID = 0;
        this.Title = null;
        this.Enabled = true;
        this.Created = DateTime.Now;
        this.CreatedBy = 0;
        this.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        this.UpdatedBy = 0;
    }

    public Scorecard(int scorecardid, int vendorid, string title, bool enabled, DateTime created, int createdby, DateTime lastupdated, int updatedby)
    {
        this.ScorecardID = scorecardid;
        this.VendorID = vendorid;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Enabled = enabled;
        this.Created = created;
        this.CreatedBy = createdby;
        this.LastUpdated = lastupdated;
        this.UpdatedBy = updatedby;
    }
}
```

and here is a sample of my XML file in which the data is written to!

[image]

Can anyone help me? My value cannot be null??

Comment: Note that your question have nothing to do with ASP.Net nor MVC... In future please try to scope down sample to exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

**One of your `item` elements does not contain all elements you're looking for.**

The exception you're getting is thrown when you're trying cast `(XElement)null` to non-nullable value type, like `int` or `DateTime`:

```
XElement t = null;
int v = (int)t;
```

Possible solutions? Change your properties to `Nullable<T>` or make sure element you're trying to cast to value type do exist in your XML document.